# Number of ways to color faces of a cube with exactly 6 colors?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, polya-counting-theory

Consider two colorings the same, if each color has the same collection of neighboring colors. I've seen Polya enumeration theorem on how to color a cube with up to $m$ colors, but that doesn't work here because I want to use exactly 6 colors. I like to think the answer is 15 because once I have two adjacent colors fixed, the rest of the cube colors itself.

I want to know if there is a generalized way to count the number of colorings for a graph with $n$ verticies with exactly $n$ colors. (perhaps to Polya enumeration theory) BTW the question was originally about coloring vertex of an octohedron.

Comment: I might be able to use PET on all colorings with less than $n$ colors, and subtract it from PET with $n$ colors, being careful to inclusion-exclusion for the over counting. Or maybe some Mobius inversion technique might work... Just some ideas,

Comment: I think $15$ is correct. Note the OP's definition: colorings are the same "if each color has the same collection of neighboring colors". Usually you only consider rotations of the cube, but here reflected colorings are also considered the same. So the remaining four colors can be arranged only in $3$ ways. If A is bottom, B is top, and CDEF are remaining, you can arrange them circularly CDEF, CDFE or CEDF (but clockwise and counterclockwise are equivalent).

Comment: Given the identification by the "set of neighbor colors", the count amounts to the number of ways to partition a set of size $6$  into $3$ pieces of size $2$ (by clumping each color with it's opposite color on the cube). This just $C(6,2)C(4,2)C(2,2) / 3! = 15$ or if you want: "#(Red's partner X) times #(the partner of the first non-Red,X)" giving $5x3=15$.

Comment: @Ned Thanks for that nice formula. It expresses what I intuitively thought.